# Redirect user to different page depending on submitting or closing infopath form

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have created an infopath form in a sharepoint 2010 site, this is accessed via a button on the home page that redirects the user to the form in the browser. I have modified the source of the button link to redirect the user to a thank you page when the form is submitted. Unfortunately this also causes the user to be redirected to the thank you page if they close the form. Is there a way to change the source of my button link so that it will redirect to the thank you page when submitted, and redirect back to the home page when the form is closed? Alternatively can this be done with some control in the infopath form? I am also open to a javascript or jquery solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source in the URL is your only choice for redirecting user upon submitting in Infopath without server-side coding. I suggest moving out of infopath and trying different approach in customizing SharePoint. Infopath is quite limited in terms of customization.

Comment: Thanks for the response Billy, unfortunately using infopath is a requirement of the client so there is not much I can do there.

Answer (score 0):

In Infopath 2013, we created the Rule "Switch View", when the User click on Submit button. This redirect the User to "Thank you" View/Page. This worked for me.